# Send "Request new password" email for individual users

Tags: users

I'm looking for a way for the administrator users to quickly send out a password reset for a specific user. Ideally, this would be a link/check on the account edit.

I have seen and made use of the [Mass Password Reset](https://www.drupal.org/project/mass_pwreset) module which works per role, but I need it for individuals too.

At the moment my thought is to make a "reset password" role then have a rule along the lines of: after saving user, if user has "reset password" role, send account recovery email, remove "reset password" role, but that seems pretty convoluted. Am I missing an easy solution?

I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd create an appropriate view (using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)) of your users, wit whatever filter criteria you'd want, you could use that view to combine it with the [Rules Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_link) module. And with that you have the full power of the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module available also to implement whatever logic you'd want.

Refer to the accepted answer to "[How to show authorized users a link for relevant Views results using the Rules Link module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/249719/39516)" for an in depth explanation about using the [Rules Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_link) module, related to a scenario which is a variation of your question here (i.e. show a link to unblock blocked users).

Comment: thanks, that makes sense - not too different to my solution but more intuitive  for users i bet

Comment: @user3016811 thank you for your comment, Not sure if I correctly translate it, but maybe you want to consider marking my answer as accepted? Similar to what is mentioned [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) ...